# Slow load times with browsersync

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, gulp

I'm working on a medium-sized React app. I have a gulp task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    browserify(paths.jsx)
        .transform(babelify,{presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle().on('error', $.notify.onError({
      title: "JSX Error",
      message: "<%= error.message %>"
    }))
    .pipe(source('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/components'));
});
```

and a watch task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'js','bs-client'], () => {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.jsx',['js']);
    gulp.watch('app/components/app.min.js', reload);
    gulp.watch(paths.srcCSS + '**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

Compiling  changes to JS is very quick:

```
[21:24:05] Starting 'js'...
[21:24:05] Finished 'js' after 6.01 ms
```

But browser sync seems to take somewhere between 7-10 seconds before it notices the change and reloads the page. If I manually go to the browser and refresh after the JS task finishes and before the browser sync reload triggers, I don't see any of my changes taking effect (like adding in a console.log, for example), so I'm assuming there's some kind of intermediary 'step' that needs to happen behind the scenes.

Why does browser sync take so long to notice the JS task has completed and reload the browser? Is there any way I can speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Browser sync has to wait for the following things:

- Files being written to the file system
- Finding differences within the files
- Creation of sourcemaps and minified files
- Compilation of SASS files

In order to speed up the process, separate the following:

- Minimal steps (copying files, creating script tags)
- Environment specific steps (sourcemaps, minification)

into separate namespaces to optimize for development.

**References**

- [Mike Valstar - Faster Gulp, Browserify, Babelify, Watchify and React build process explained.](http://mikevalstar.com/post/fast-gulp-browserify-babelify-watchify-react-build/)
- [Dynamic environments for your gulp tasks – Wolox Driving Innovation – Medium](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/dynamic-environments-for-your-gulp-tasks-27fada475c7e)
- [gulp: A Streaming Build System](http://blog.airasoul.io/gulp-a-streaming-build-system/)
- [Explore encouraging users to not ship DEV mode to production · Issue #8784 · facebook/react](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8784)